# How to display multiple user's profiles on a single view MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a page where users can view all the profiles from a single database in a single view. In this case, I have an Investors table which has a list of investors and a Files table used to store the investors profile picture. When investors are logged in they can see their profile details including their profile picture. Now I am trying to get the same view but with all the investors profiles and profile pictures showing, without an investor needing to log into their account.

My current solution shows all the investors in a table but without the pictures. Can someone please help me with including the profile pictures.

I have the following investor controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BG.Models;

namespace BG.Controllers
{
public class InvestorController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    //Get: Weather
    public ActionResult Weather()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //Get: CropCycle
    public ActionResult CropCycle()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //Get: RainfallHistory
    public ActionResult RainfallHistory()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Investor
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Investor.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Investor/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        Investor investor = db.Investor.Where(c => c.Email == User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();

        if (investor == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        return View(investor);
    }

    // GET: Investor/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Investor/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "InvestorID,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,MinLimit,MaxLimit,Address,Photo")] Investor investor, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var avatar = new File
                {
                    FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                    FileType = FileType.Avatar,
                    ContentType = upload.ContentType
                };
                using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                {
                    avatar.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                }
                investor.Files = new List<File> { avatar };
            }
            db.Investor.Add(investor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Session["userName"] = investor.FirstName;
            Session["investorID"] = investor.InvestorID;
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }

        return View(investor);
    }




    // GET: Investor/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        //select the client to edit, identified by user email (unique index)
        Investor investor = db.Investor.Where(c => c.Email == User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();
        if (investor == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        return View(investor);
    }

    // POST: Investor/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "InvestorID,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,MinLimit,MaxLimit,Address,Photo")] Investor investor)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(investor).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                Session["userName"] = investor.FirstName;
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }

        }
        catch (DataException dex)
        {         //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.      
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(investor);
    }

    // GET: Investor/Delete/5
    //public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    //{
    //    if (id == null)
    //    {
    //        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    //    }
    //    Investor investor = db.Investor.Find(id);
    //    if (investor == null)
    //    {
    //        return HttpNotFound();
    //    }
    //    return View(investor);
    //}

    //// POST: Investor/Delete/5
    //[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    //{
    //    Investor investor = db.Investor.Find(id);
    //    db.Investor.Remove(investor);
    //    db.SaveChanges();
    //    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    //}

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

This is the File Controller

```
namespace BG.Controllers
{
public class FileController : Controller
{

    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    // GET: File
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var fileToRetrieve = db.Files.Find(id);
        return File(fileToRetrieve.Content, fileToRetrieve.ContentType);
    }
}
```

The investor model

```
public class Investor
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InvestorID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You cannot leave the first name blank.")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be more than 20 characters long.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You cannot leave the last name blank.")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Last name cannot be more than 20 characters long.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You cannot leave the email blank.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "Email address is too long.")]
    //ensuring one to one relationship between investor profile info and users in the identity system.
    [Index("IX_Unique_Email", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide a phone number")]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number (no spaces).")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public float MinLimit { get; set; }
    public float MaxLimit { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Investment> Investment { get; set; }
}
```

The file model

```
public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public int InvestorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Investor investor { get; set; }
}
```

The investor view that I am trying to display from

```
@model IEnumerable<BG.Models.Investor>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Investors</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MinLimit)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MaxLimit)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Photo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MinLimit)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MaxLimit)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Photo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>

        <td>
            <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Send Request</button></p>
        </td>

    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it fits a [mcve] (with emphasis on the minimal part).

Comment: One Investor object can have more than one file, which file you want to display ? All of them ?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a view model, the whole MVC(Model-View-Controller), just change your model yo suite your needs.